# How do i make the first of two strokes on text transparent so it shows through the bottom stroke layer?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, appearance

I was wondering if it's possible to put a double stroke on text so that the inner stroke makes it transparent and you can see the background. Basically it will be a solid text, then an outline which you can see what's behind it, then another solid outline. And keeping it all editable as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to apply two strokes for that you can simply apply one stroke and then off-set the path to positive number. It automatically leave some space between your solid fill colour and the stroke.

Here's the method

1. Type the Text and add the fill colour and outer stroke colour you want.

[image]

2. Go to you your appearance panel(Shift+F6) select the stroke.

[image]

3. Now in appearance panel select Add new Effect > Path > Offset path

[image]

4. Enter an appropriate value to get the desired result

[image]

DONE!

Note: You might need to set the tracking to some Positive number as when you offset the path characters do not attach themselves to each other

Comment: This works for the example shown, but I also would like to off set the fill or stroke in the back so it appears as a shadow with empty space between the top fill and the "shadow" fill. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a stroke offset effect to push the stroke away from your type. I believe it's doable with live type.